# What is best way to learn Magento?

Tags: magento-1.8, magento-1.9, magento-community, extensions

But I want to be expert .Not just someone who knows how to make settings in admin panel. Lots of books are small one.i want better resource I guess spanning over 1000 pages like java complete reference book.I dont have money (8 lakhs indian rupees) to spend on expensive vids on official site.

Comment: Can anyone answer ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest that you start with the basics, which you already can find in small books like "[Magento PHP Developer's Guide](https://www.packtpub.com/web-development/magento-php-developer%E2%80%99s-guide)" or similar.

And then, besides of a running Magento installation and a powerful IDE (I prefer PhpStorm), you need a lot of time for hands on.

Try to dig deep into the core of Magento, the [official and free study guide](http://info.magento.com/rs/magentocommerce/images/Certification-Study-Guide-MCD-v1.pdf) is a good way to start.

And last but not least, code, code, code, code......

It took me at least more than a year working with Magento until I was able to pass the Magento Certified Developer exam.

Answer (score 1):

Magento is an e-commerce solution built with php and JavaScript. To learn Magento, you first have to be comfortable with php and JavaScript.

Learning Magento could be initially intimidating, so you will have to be consistent and persistent in your efforts to study. 
There are lots of vidoes on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=magento%202%20developer%20tutorial) that introduce various aspects of development in Magento, I suggest you spend sometime to watch a lot of them. This will make you familiar with how things are done and what to expect.

I also suggest taking some courses on udemy, these worked for me:

- [Learning Path: Magento: Master and Test Magento 2 with Ease](https://www.udemy.com/learning-path-magento-master-and-test-magento-2-with-ease/)
- [Mastering Magento 2](https://www.udemy.com/mastering-magento-2/)

And finally, you need to practise. You need to build different extensions to build your confidence.

The best examples of code are in the core Magento modules (located in `vendor/magento` directory), so often spend time understanding how it works.